# R: Gwidget simpleError in envRefInferField , from gedit

Tags: r, gwidgets

I know this has been asked last year but I have searched for several days now and I still cannot seem to be able to resolve the following issue:

```
txt_outputDataFile <- gedit(initial.msg="desired output file", container=row2)
```

generates the following error:

Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘no_items’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Entry”

I am using RStudio  version 0.98.507 and the following two lines in my code:

```
require("gWidgets")
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")
```

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this error, or how I can access the value from this field in a different manner? Thank you.

Comment: This comes up with RStudio. I only see it reported with `gWidgets`, you might try `gWidgets2` to see if that works. Most code needs no change.

Comment: @jverzani Thank you. I will check it out. Incidentally, if you have txt_inputDataFile <- gedit(text = NULL, initial.msg="input .txt file", container=row1) and try to update the value using svalue(txt_inputDataFile) <- svalue(file), the initial.msg gets updated and not the text. This update only works if initial text is provided.

Comment: Yup, that's a bug. The value gets updated, but not the text color. Thanks, I'll push a fix to r-forge.